# How to initiate an action when shutting down the emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I want to make an action that occurs when I shutdown the emulator. More specifically I want to write to a file before the emulator shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering a BroadCastReceiver for https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SHUTDOWN intent.
You might need a Service or Activity running to receive it.

Comment: So I did that already, and that works fine, but I need something for when the emulator is shutdown, that is when you press the X button.

Comment: Sorry I answered assuming you wanted your application to know when the device is shutdown using the Power key. I am not aware of any Android SDK API which will tell app about closing emulator window.